# How do I store emails into my SQL server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, insert, addition

I am trying to store emails into my SQL server database. These emails I got from Exchange Webservices.

I am using entity Framework and made a ADO .Net Data Model.

My Question is how do I make a method(StoreEmail) that stores these emails into my database.

This is my StoreEmail method that I got so far:

It should store my PhishingMails...

```
          public object StoreMail(Model.PhishingMail PhishingMail)
         {
           using (var phishingMailStorage = new PhishFinderModel())
        {
            PhishingMail = MailMapper.Map(Model.PhishingMail);
            phishingMailStorage.PhishingMails.Add();

            phishingMailStorage.SaveChanges();

            return PhishingMail;
        }

    }
```

In Mailmapper class I set the properties that I want to store, which are Sender, Subject and Body:

```
      public static PhishingMail Map(EmailMessage OutlookMail)
    {


        PhishingMail readMail = new PhishingMail();

        readMail.Sender = OutlookMail.Sender.Address;
        readMail.Body = OutlookMail.Body;

         return readMail;

  }
```

This is my DB schema[image]

To clarify my question, I already get the list of emails from the exchange server. Now, all I need to do is insert them into the SQL server.

How do I make my StoreEmail method work to do this?

Please don't be harsh I am really new to this. It feels like I am swimming in an ocean of information and I don't know where to look or start. So any suggested tutorials are very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing `PhishingMail`, and you're receiving a `PhishingMail`, so you don't need your mapping step.

Does this not work?

```
public void StoreMail(Model.PhishingMail PhishingMail)
{
    using (var phishingMailStorage = new PhishFinderModel())
    {
        phishingMailStorage.PhishingMails.Add(PhishingMail);

        phishingMailStorage.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You don't need to return the mail, either, since the caller already has it (and it's a lot tidier to have a `void` return if you're not returning a new/different object.

If you *actually* need to store an `EmailMessage`, your method should be:

```
public void StoreMail(EmailMessage emailMessage)
{
    var phishingMail = MailMapper.Map(emailMessage);
    using (var phishingMailStorage = new PhishFinderModel())
    {
        phishingMailStorage.PhishingMails.Add(phishingMail);

        phishingMailStorage.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3599415 Okay, in that case, you need to change your `Map` method to create and return a `DataAccess.PhishingMail` instead of `PhishingMail` (which is being resolved automatically to `Model.PhishingMail`). Essentially, in your `Map` method, replace `PhishingMail` with `DataAccess.PhishingMail`.

Comment: @user3599415 No worries :)